# Java Recursion Backtracking with Specific Methods (Sudoku)

Tags: java, recursion, backtracking

I'm working on a Java program for an assignment and I've been stuck on the implementation and don't know where else to look for help. The assignment is to create a Backtracking Java program that will solve a given Sudoku board using a few Required Methods:

**Required Methods:**

• **isFullSolution**, a method that accepts a partial solution and returns true if it is a complete, valid solution.

• **reject**, a method that accepts a partial solution and returns true if it should be rejected because it can never be extended into a complete solution.

• **extend**, a method that accepts a partial solution and returns another partial solution that includes one additional choice added on. This method will return null if there are no more choices to add to the solution. It should also be sure to make a new partial solution, rather than modifying the original object

• **next**, a method that accepts a partial solution and returns another partial solution in which the most recent choice to be added has been changed to its next option. This method will return null if there are no more options for the most recent choice that was made.

We're also given our **Solve** method here:

```
 static int[][] solve(int[][] board) {
    if (reject(board)) return null; 
    if (isFullSolution(board)) return board; 
    int[][] attempt = extend(board);
    while (attempt != null) {
        int[][] solution = solve(attempt);
        if (solution != null) return solution;
        attempt = next(attempt);
    }
    return null;
}
```

I have 3 Major Questions relating to implementing this.

I could easily solve this without having to deal with the **Extend**, **Next**, and the premade **Solve** methods.

**1.** Would **Extend** just find the first 0 (0's are used as empty spaces) and replace it with a 1; so the next method could compare that using methods to compare to Row, Column, and Box? And even if I am right in assuming that the **Solve** method never reaches the **Next** method in any of my tests and I don't know how to work around it.

My **Extend** Method:

```
static int[][] extend(int[][] board) {
  // Initialize the new partial solution
  int[][] temp = new int[9][9];
  for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++){
      temp[i][j] = board[i][j];
    }
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++){
      if(temp[i][j] == 0){
        temp[i][j] = 1;
        return temp;
      }
    }
  }
  //If we reach this, can no longer extend
   return null;
}
```

**2.** The **Next** method is never reached unless explicitly called by me inside the **Extend** method. I have written a lot of different methods for this and none of them work for different reasons. I have comparing methods for the row, column, and box to check which value CAN be placed and if none work it is set to 0. **However**, through all of my tests it never changed any of the 1's set by the **Extend** method. I honestly just get very confused and lost at this point and any guidance would be great.

**3.** Finally, how would I know which cases to reject for my **Reject** method? I feel like there are just an infinite amount of corner-cases for a sudoku board when any board can be put in.

I'm just incredibly lost and have no idea how to proceed. Any and All help is welcome.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  Specifically, you haven't shown us a single line of your attempts to debug this, just generalities of your (missing) test cases.

Answer (score 1):

**Summary** -- my opinions; see caveats below.

1. Extend can, indeed, just put a '1' in place of a '0' -- or may need to check RCB (Row Column Box) for conflicts first.  You'll save some execution time with the checking.
2. Your first sentence is incorrect.  See the overview below.  As for the overall confusion, there's no way we can help you without the code and symptoms.  Post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you still have trouble.
3. I expect that you can just check for immediate RCB conflicts.  The logic flow is set up to handle the more complex cases with recursive search.

**Overview**

I feel that you've confused two sets of problems here: (1) Specification problems, which you need to clarify with your instructor; (2) Coding problems, which you need to specify properly for Stack Overflow.

Under (1) is the extent of work done by each of your methods.  First of all, your assumption about invoking **next** is incorrect; the main loop of **solve** will call **next** whenever a particular board fails to provide a solution.

**Top-level Logic**

In English (pseudo-code), your given **solve** routine works something like this:

```
If the board has no solution, return null.
If the board *is* a solution, return it.
If neither of those ...
    attempt = extend the board one guess
    while there's still a valid attempt ...
        if there is a solution for this attempt, return it.
        else alter attempt to the next guess.
```

This last line is where **next** gets called on a regular basis.

**Partition of the Issues**

Open questions, with my opinions (if I were assigning this to my students):

- Does **extend** check for first-order validity (check RCB -- Row, Column, Box -- for conflict with existing numbers) of the new guess?  If not, then replacing a 0 with a 1 works fine.
- Does **reject** check only for first-order validity, or does it have to determine whether a solution exists?  I suspect that it's the simple check, given the logic flow you've posted.